# Como mudar o formato data de "ano/mês/dia" para "ano/mês" no R?

Tags: r, data

Suponhamos que tenho uma data no formato padrão inglês `"ymd"`, exemplo:

```
Sys.Date()

"2019-04-11"
```

Sendo que para a minha análise não tenho a necessidade que esta data tenha os dias e decido retirá-los, para que tenha um formato mais simples: `"2019-04"`.

Como faço para mudar o formato data de "ano/mês/dia" para somente "ano/mês"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eis duas maneiras diferentes de converter uma data para `"ano/mês"`.

**R base.**
Usar o método `format.Date` para objetos de classe `"Date"`.

```
format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m")
#[1] "2019-04"
```

**Pacote `zoo`.**
A função `as.yearmon` faz isso mesmo.

```
zoo::as.yearmon(Sys.Date())
#[1] "abr 2019"
```